# ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here?

Tags: sql, oracle, average, having

I need a list of movies with a certain average rating to show up.  I know that the problem is with the HAVING clause, but I'm not sure as to how to fix it.  Without that clause it works, and it lists all movie/actor combos that follow the specified qualities, but I need them to also have an average rating above 4 (which is what I'm trying to do with the having clause).

With the HAVING clause it says ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here.  Anybody know how I can fix this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.title "Movie Title",
   ROUND(AVG(r.rating) OVER (PARTITION BY m.movieid, a.actorid),2) "Average Rating",
   a.afname||' '||a.alname "Name",
   m.ryear
FROM netflix.actors a JOIN netflix.movies_actors ma
   ON a.actorid = ma.actorid
JOIN netflix.movies m
   ON ma.movieid = m.movieid
JOIN netflix.ratings100 r
   ON m.movieid = r.movieid
JOIN netflix.movies_genres g
   ON m.movieid = g.movieid
WHERE a.gender LIKE 'F'
   AND g.genrecode LIKE 'DRM'
   AND m.ryear >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')-12
HAVING AVG(r.rating) OVER (PARTITION BY m.movieid, a.actorid) >= 4
ORDER BY "Average Rating" desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics functions can't use in `WHERE` or `HAVING` bloks. They make calculations for the resultset in `SELECT`-block. And also you use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` it's an error, too.
I think you can use a subquery and `WHERE` for it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT m.title "Movie Title",
       ROUND(AVG(r.rating) OVER (PARTITION BY m.movieid, a.actorid),2) "Average Rating",
       a.afname||' '||a.alname "Name",
       m.ryear
    FROM netflix.actors a JOIN netflix.movies_actors ma
       ON a.actorid = ma.actorid
    JOIN netflix.movies m
       ON ma.movieid = m.movieid
    JOIN netflix.ratings100 r
       ON m.movieid = r.movieid
    JOIN netflix.movies_genres g
       ON m.movieid = g.movieid
    WHERE a.gender LIKE 'F'
       AND g.genrecode LIKE 'DRM'
       AND m.ryear >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')-12
  )
WHERE "Average Rating" >= 4
ORDER BY "Average Rating" desc
```

Answer (score 0):

windowing or analytic function are allowed only in select statements.
so you can filter like this:

```
    select * from (
    SELECT DISTINCT m.title "Movie Title",
       ROUND(AVG(r.rating) OVER (PARTITION BY m.movieid, a.actorid),2) "Average Rating",
       a.afname||' '||a.alname "Name",
       m.ryear
    FROM netflix.actors a JOIN netflix.movies_actors ma
       ON a.actorid = ma.actorid
    JOIN netflix.movies m
       ON ma.movieid = m.movieid
    JOIN netflix.ratings100 r
       ON m.movieid = r.movieid
    JOIN netflix.movies_genres g
       ON m.movieid = g.movieid
    WHERE a.gender LIKE 'F'
       AND g.genrecode LIKE 'DRM'
       AND m.ryear >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')-12


    ) as f1
    where f1.[Average Rating] >=4
ORDER BY f1.[Average Rating] desc
```